# How get the id of an document from vuejs and firestore?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i have this code to get all of documents from firestore:

```
const getThemesList = async ({ commit }) => {
  const snapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('themes')
    .get();
  const promiseThemes = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  commit(types.GET_THEMES, promiseThemes);
};
```

by that fuction i can listing, each item have a delete button:

```
<v-btn text @click="deleteTheme(item)">
        Delete
      </v-btn>
```

each item only have these parameters:

```
{
description: (...)
name: (...)
type: (...)
}
```

but how can i delete an item, if i dont have their id?

```
db.collection('themes')
    .doc(theme.id)
    .delete()
    .then(function() {
```

how can i get the id? theme.id?

[image]

Edit 1:
i have this wrong with @DougStevenson's answer

[image]

Comment: you should probably keep the id of the document on the client-side, that way you can query by id (and delete accordingly)

Comment: @DenisTsoi i am working only on frontend side

Comment: if you dont have the id, you need to query based on the document - and hope your firebase can find that document (and delete it)

Comment: @DenisTsoi can you create  your answer please_?

Comment: one second - working on another question right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doc` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) that has an `id` property.  Just add the document ID into each item object that you generate:

```
const promiseThemes = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {id: doc.id, ...doc.data());
```

Now you have an object with an `id` property that you can use to delete the document.

Comment: According to the edit on your question, you didn't use exactly what I provided.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  The only goal you have is to inject the id of the document into the object that you map to each DocumentSnapshot.  You can do that any way you like.

Comment: i put a new image