# Firestore: How do I get the doc names of the results of a Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I have this firestore query:

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
```

It returns all documents from the colletion `cities` that match the where clause, as expected. However, how can I get the names (or: ids?) of the documents that are returned?

I use the query with vue.js and vuexfire like this:

```
bindCities: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
  var query = db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
  return bindFirestoreRef("cities", query);
}),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get the id of an document from vuejs and firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959382/how-get-the-id-of-an-document-from-vuejs-and-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

`doc.id` would help you get the document id/name.

```js
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    const documentsID = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id)
    // do something with documents
  })
```